# How to run Apache Tez Locally?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins, apache-tez

One of the ways that one can execute tez is in local mode beside integrated with hadoop. In order to run it localy
I read [this page](https://tez.apache.org/localmode.html) and understood the changes I have to make and I updated tez-site.xml configuration. But I don't know how to start it.

I tried running one of the tez-examples (e.g. wordCount) that has a main method. But it stalls and don't print anything to stdout. Is there anything that I have to start first?

How can I run tez in local mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run it with including needed libraries. I could changing pom and build the final jar file with the dependencies, but I preferred not to change the project.

After building it with `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`

I ran it with setting java classpath:

```
java -cp tez-dist/target/tez-0.7.0/lib/*:tez-dist/target/tez-0.7.0/* org.apache.tez.examples.OrderedWordCount in.txt out
```